# mysql table with varchar primary key field

Tags: mysql, cakephp, phpmyadmin

I have create users table with following structure

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
   `id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
   `first_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   `last_name` varchar(100) NULL,
   `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I just want to auto filled id value when we insert new row.

Comment: If you don't want to use mysql's auto_increment feature you will have to code what you do want possibly in a trigger or your front end app.

Comment: @P.Salmon can you please help me with code. I have tried but not get it

Comment: If you have a problem with the answer I provided can you add a comment to it please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do wish to generate a uuid in conjuntion with a trigger then your table design has some problems for example

```
drop table if exists t;
CREATE TABLE t (
   `id` varchar(36) not null,
   `first_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   `last_name` varchar(100) NULL,
   `email` varchar(100) NULL,
   `password` varchar(100) NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ;

drop trigger if exists t;
delimiter $$
create trigger t before insert on t
for each row 

begin

        set new.id = (select uuid());

end $$

delimiter ;
truncate table t;
insert into t (first_name) values (1),(2);
ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'id' doesn't have a default value
```

And you cannot use a default value because a duplicate error will occur when attempting to insert (2);
And you cannot change the not null to null because the primary key has to have a value.

You **can** change the id to null and change the primary key to a unique key

```
drop table if exists t;
CREATE TABLE t (
   `id` varchar(36) null,
   `first_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   `last_name` varchar(100) NULL,
   `email` varchar(100) NULL,
   `password` varchar(100) NULL ,
    unique key (`id`)
) ;

drop trigger if exists t;
create trigger t before insert on t
for each row 
        set new.id = (select uuid());


truncate table t;
insert into t (first_name) values (1),(2);
select * from t;
+--------------------------------------+------------+-----------+-------+----------+
| id                                   | first_name | last_name | email | password |
+--------------------------------------+------------+-----------+-------+----------+
| 874bd297-adeb-11e8-b404-b8aeed249e19 | 1          | NULL      | NULL  | NULL     |
| 874bda27-adeb-11e8-b404-b8aeed249e19 | 2          | NULL      | NULL  | NULL     |
+--------------------------------------+------------+-----------+-------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: So it is not possible for primary keys?

Answer (score 1):

Try `id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `first_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   `last_name` varchar(100) NULL,
   `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to make a VARCHAR column auto incrementing.  You Can't Do That™.

VARCHAR columns containing the text of integers are notoriously hard to ORDER correctly.

In MySQL, an automatically filled (autoincrementing) ID column must have an integer datatype.

Try changing

```
    `id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
```

to

```
    `id` UNSIGNED BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

(I chose UNSIGNED BIGINT because it's the largest integer available, and your choice of 36 in your VARCHAR(36) makes it look like you are expecting  an enormous number of rows in this table. But UNSIGNED INT will give you four gigarows, which is probably enough.)

If you choose to use a trigger or some other means to generate the autoincrementing  values for your VARCHAR ID column, you will have to do a lot of hard work with transactions to avoid the possibility of duplicate values.

If your client software must see this column as a VARCHAR, you can do it in a view or select.  `SELECT CAST(id AS VARCHAR(36)) id` does it.

Comment: Length of 36 might indicate he wants to use a GUID.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want an automatically generated GUID for the primary key, this only seems possible in MySql using a trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_users
BEFORE INSERT ON users
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF new.id IS NULL THEN
    SET new.id = uuid();
  END IF;
END
```

More information can be found here:
https://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-guid-uuid-default-column/

Comment: The table would have to be redesigned to make this work -for example id is not null and will fail on insert (this is tested before the trigger is executed), if not null is a removed an insert will fail because a default is not set and default cannot be used because that would cause a failure on a multiple insert etc..

Comment: This can be solved by omitting the NULL check, thus overwriting the value in case it is provided.

Comment: that's not the case a you get a ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'id' doesn't have a default value. Would you like to show the table design that works for you?

Comment: That would be usefull. I don't have any MySql instance available here.

Comment: Mmm, you're right. Couldn't get it working. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd8da
Couldn't save the INSERT statement because of generated error, so it should be added manually at the end in SqlFiddle.
INSERT INTO `users` (`first_name`, `email`, `password`) VALUES
  ('name1', 'email1', '1111'),
  ('name2', 'email2', '2222')

Answer (score 0):

According to  [Cookbook 3.x](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions):

> Rather than using an auto-increment key as the primary key, you may
>   also use char(36). CakePHP will then use a unique 36 character UUID
>   (Text::uuid) whenever you save a new record using the Table::save()
>   method.

Means CakePHP automatically saves a unique 36 character **UUID (Text::uuid)** whenever you save a new record using the Table::save() method.

**Just change**

```
 id varchar(36) NOT NULL
```

**to**

```
 id char(36) NOT NULL
```

Hope this will help!